# When calling a contract from an other contract, what happends if the value of callgas argument is above availaible gas?

Tags: gas, contract-invocation, gas-limit, out-of-gas

In such case, the value is replaced with available gas right ?
Or Does an out of gas exception is thrown ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the value is replaced with available gas right?

As a bit of a simplification, yes.

IIRC, I believe the amount of gas forwarded to the callee is actually 63/64ths of the remaining gas in the transaction.